# How to decode array of Javascript object encoded with x-www-form-urlencoded?

Tags: node.js, express, url-encoding

I send following array with POST request:

```
let bookings = [{
  owner       : clientId,
  businessId  : businessId,
  service     : serviceId,
  startDate   : new Date()
}, {
  owner       : clientId,
  businessId  : businessId,
  service     : serviceId,
  startDate   : new Date()
}];
```

On server I have following setup:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

and get the following `req.body` content:

```
0[owner]=56fd4dcf8b98ce1c3d87e3ad, 0[businessId]=56fd4dcf8b98ce1c3d87e3ac, 0[service]=56fd4dcf8b98ce1c3d87e3ab, 0[startDate]=2016-03-31T16:18:23.220Z, 1[owner]=56fd4dcf8b98ce1c3d87e3ad, 1[businessId]=56fd4dcf8b98ce1c3d87e3ac, 1[service]=56fd4dcf8b98ce1c3d87e3ab, 1[startDate]=2016-03-31T16:18:23.220Z
```

How can I decode this back to JavaScript array of objects ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through `body-parser` use the [`urlencoded()`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions) function.

`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));`

> **extended**
>
> The extended option allows to choose between parsing the URL-encoded data with the querystring library (when false) or the qs library (when true). The "extended" syntax allows for rich objects and arrays to be encoded into the URL-encoded format, allowing for a JSON-like experience with URL-encoded. For more information, please see the qs library.
>
> Defaults to true, but using the default has been deprecated. Please research into the difference between qs and querystring and choose the appropriate setting.